# Which alias module better to use?

Tags: perl

I want to alias values from `source` array to hash values

```
@$data{ $sth->{NAME_lc}->@* } =  $self->source->@*;
```

What is the best way to accomplish this task?

**UPD**
Here I want hash value refer to array value. And if hash value is changed the corresponding value in array must be changed too

Comment: What do you mean by alias?

Comment: "Best" is rather unspecific. What are your criteria?

Comment: @Shawn: I mean [this](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=976523): An `alias` is another name that refers to the same thing as the first.

Comment: What Perl version are you using? `use experimental 'refaliasing'` may be the least brittle solution.

Comment: My own preference is not to create any aliases. If possible, I'd just use references manually.

Comment: @melpomene: Here is specific case when we want to escape values copying

Comment: @amon: this `\@$data{ $sth->{NAME_lc}->@* } =  \$self->source->@*` does not work =( This either: `\[@$data{ $sth->{NAME_lc}->@* }] =  \$self->source->@*`

Comment: I didn't say copy the values, I said use references.

Comment: @melpomene: Thus access syntax will be different: `${$data->{field}}` instead of `$data->{field}`

Comment: It' seems you can't always ref-alias lists but only single values. Would `\$data->{ $sth->{NAME_lc}->[$_] } =  \$self->source->[$_] for 0 .. $#{ $self->source }` work?

Comment: @amon: We can. You give me the idea. See answer

Answer (score 1):

I have found this solution:

```
use Data::Alias;
alias @$data{ $sth->{NAME_lc}->@* } =  $self->source->@*;
```

**UPD**
Thanks **@amon** for [`refaliasing`](https://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html#The-%27refaliasing%27-feature)[`lists`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References):

```
\(@$data{ $sth->{NAME_lc}->@* }) =  \($self->source->@*)
```

**UPD**
Seems last examples does not work. Aliases are lexically scoped. reported as [RT#133538](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=133538)

`Data::Alias` still works fine

**UPD**
`Data::Alias` is most `++` aliasing module on [metacpan.org](http://metacpan.org/) so I think it is the best method as of today. Until `refaliasing` feature will be fixed.

Comment: I don't think you've answered your question. How have you determined that `Data::Alias` is *"the best way to accomplish this task"*?

Comment: @Borodin: This module is most `++` on metacpan. So I think it is the best